# How to vertically align the contents of cells in NiceTabular?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, nicematrix, makecell

I am trying to to vertically align cells contents in `NiceTabular` when they get significantly different heights. However, `\adjustbox` and `makecell` do not seem to work (neither does `\adjustbox` and `\Block`). Also, `\adjustbox` seems to provide no good alignment at the baseline of different rows (e.g., 2nd, 4th and 5th rows)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

{\centering
    
    \begin{NiceTabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}[code-before=\cellcolor{DodgerBlue3}{3-1,2-2,1-3}, hvlines]
        \hline
        \adjustbox{valign=m}{a} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{b} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth]{example-image-C}}
        \\
        \hline
        \adjustbox{valign=m}{e} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{f} & g
        \\
        \hline
        h & i & \makecell[c]{j \\ basmah \\ shafaamri}
        \\
        \adjustbox{valign=b}{h} & \adjustbox{valign=b}{i} & \adjustbox{valign=b}{\makecell[c]{j \\ basmah \\ shafaamri}}
        \\
        \adjustbox{valign=b}{h} & \adjustbox{valign=b}{i} & \adjustbox{valign=b}{\Block{1-1}{j \\ basmah \\ shafaamri}}
        \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}

}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things with `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

    
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}[code-before=\cellcolor{DodgerBlue3}{3-1,2-2,1-3}, hvlines]
\hline
a & b & \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-c} \\
\hline
a & b & \includegraphics[width=0.47\linewidth,valign=b]{example-image-c} \\
\hline
e & f & g \\
\hline
h & i & \makecell[c]{j \\ basmah \\ shafaamri} \\
h & i & \makecell[b]{j \\ basmah \\ shafaamri} \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]